# Differences in Nuance Omnipage v16 and v19

Tags: .net, ocr

We are looking to upgrade from OmnipageSDK v16 to v19. We need the output from Omnipage Formatted Text to match v16 since we have business logic dependent on this output.

I am getting inconsistent results using the same output settings (Converters.Text.FormattedTxt) between the versions.

The big issue is that the output text has different spacing between versions. After trying to test this I think the cause might be that v19 is reading different font sizes for the text and when it is converting these to plain text it is adding spaces to compensate for the larger font sizes.

I'm still looking at the documentation and haven't heard back from Nuance with any suggestions yet.

If you have any similar experience with this please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified with Nuance that the formatted output is different in v19. v16 had nice fixed text output and oddly v19 is very unpredictable with the text output which makes it useless when trying to parse the text.